# Finding Extreme Values (Multivariable)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Given $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$, find its extreme values on $x^2+y^2=1$. I know how to solve this problem using Lagrange's method and the constant variation method.

The solutions are $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$ and is easily achieved using Lagrange's method.

If we go about the constant variation method, say we fix x and analyse f(y) for critical points, we get:

$$f(y)= \left (\pm \sqrt{1-y^2} \right)^2 +2y^2 \implies f(y)=y^2+1$$
$$f'(y)=2y, \text{critical points where f = 0} \implies (\pm1,0) \text{is critical} $$

However this method does not give us the second set of critical coordinates $(0,\pm1)$ unless we repeat the same process but analyzing $f(x)$.

I find this weird because fixing x on the given constraint is analysing the critical points on the entire circle which is the same thing we are doing when fixing y.

---

My question is:
Why do we have to do 2 analysis instead of 1?

Thanks

(I hope this makes sense!)

Comment: You need to check whether the extrema are maxima or minima.  Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution $1$:

$f(x) = x^2+y^2 + y^2 = 1+y^2 \geq 1$, and $\leq 2$. Can you take it from here?

Solution $2$:

$f(x) = x^2+2y^2 \geq 1^{x^2}2^{y^2}=2^{y^2} \geq 2^{0}=1$, and $f(x) \leq 2x^2+2y^2 = 2(x^2+y^2) = 2$. Can you take it from here also?

Solution $3$:

Let $x =\cos \theta, y = \sin \theta\to f=\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta=1+\sin^2\theta\geq 1, \leq 2$ since $0 \leq \sin^2\theta \leq 1$.

Comment: I thought $ f(x)=1-x^2$ ? and where did $ \geq1$ and $ \leq2$ come from?

Comment: Okay I see what you did for solution 1, but how did you determine that it must be $\leq2$? Also, should that ready $f(y)=1+y^2$?